# Subtraction in regex doesn't get results

Tags: php, regex

From a range of *aaaa,aaab,....zzzz* I'm trying to select using the php function preg_match. The regex are: `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]`, `[a-z-[aeiuo]]` from witch I get:

`preg_match('/[a-z-[aeiuo]]/',$line)` result: Nothing

`preg_match('/[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]/',$line)` result: `aaab,aaac,aaad,aaaf,aaag....`

These are suppose to get the same; any string where there is at least one consonant.

Why doesn't the first one get anything?. Thanks

EDIT: My only main doubt is why `[a-z-[aeiuo]]` doesn't do the same thing as `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]` that's all. I'm trying to learn, excuse me for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do to achieve something similar is to combine the full letter selection with a negative lookahead for vowels:

```
/(?![aeiou])[a-z]/
```

The `(?![aeiou])` part matches any point in the string where the next character is not `[aeiou]`. The following `[a-z]` restricts it so it would only match letters. The two combined will only match consonants.

Comment: This should have been marked as the answer. Helped me out at least ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as subtraction in regex.

`[a-z-[aeiou]]` does not mean "a-z minus [aeiou]"

Use `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]` that you already have.

Comment: There **IS** character class subtraction. Just that it is not implemented by PCRE.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I think the first RegEx expression is invalid. It processes `a-z`, then it finds a `-`, which has nothing on the left side.</s>
By placing `[` or `]` characters inside a `[]` group in RegEx, they will be processed as `[` and `]` characters, not as a separated group.

Comment: It is not invalid. It would match any letter `a` through `z` or an actual `-`

Comment: Actually, it is valid.  `-` will match a literal `-` if not part of a range and the regex would require a `]` at the end of the string to match.  However, the part about the literal `[` is correct.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know it, thanks for corrections. I'll fix the post.

Comment: isn't here also `z-[` range?

Answer (score 0):

If class subtraction is not a feature, then the first example will not result to anything.

Check this [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xmlcharclass.html) out (The second paragraph quotes your exact problem)-

> E.g. [a-z-[aeiuo]] matches a single letter that is not a vowel (i.e. a
>   single consonant). Without the character class subtraction feature,
>   the only way to do this would be to list all consonants:
>   [b-df-hj-np-tv-z].

To test what the first regex will match, read the "Your regular expression explained" section from the [Here](http://regex101.com/r/uA6mX4)

Comment: Good question. Here's a +1 to counteract it, since your answer is both correct and relevant.
Although technically it *could* find something: it will be looking for any lowercase character or a hyphen or an open square bracket, followed by a close square bracket. It essentially could be condensed to `[a-z-[]]`

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox Yep. I meant that for the characters given as input, it will give zero results. You are almost right with what it will match, check link in my edit.

Comment: The main point is that PHP doesn't support set subtraction in character classes.  The lookahead solution in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21962138/20938) works in any flavor that supports lookahead.